# Thumbnail creation in Java

Tags: java, resize, thumbnails

I want to create the thumbnails for a group of images. for that, I am using the following code.

```
public void run() {
        try{
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
    int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
            IMG_HEIGHT = (originalImage.getHeight()*600)/originalImage.getWidth();
    BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
    ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "jpg", new File(thumb));
            originalImage.flush();
            resizeImageJpg.flush();
            System.gc();

}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Not Created:"+url);
}
    }
private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type){
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
    System.gc();
return resizedImage;
}
```

This code is working fine and creating thumbnails. But the problem is that, in case of large number of images, I am getting "java heap space error".Is it the problem with this code? How can i solve this issue. Thanks in advance.
If you have any other code for resizing, please give to me.

Comment: it seems you have finished heap space. Complete the code with the cicle which you use to read all images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Image Scaling Library, it works fine for me.

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

Comment: Glad it is working for you; the entire reason I wrote it was to address this one situation (OP) really easily and really quickly: "I want thumbnails, make them for me computer!" The library has some more advanced features than that, but not much more. I have made sure to keep it as simple/small as possible so it doesn't lose scope and become another general-purpose Graphics API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are setting IMG_WIDTH, could it be that this is left  at a huge value. You should prefer to pas teh target width amd height as parameters, teh way you set teh height prevents multi-threaded usage and makes it very hard to read.  And I doubt the height of the target image is really part of an objects state.

Also, are you sure you are setting the image height correctly, the height is related to a ration between height and width, a narrow image will give you a very tall image and stretched image assuming the width of the target image is to remain constant.

One last thing, http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html has some useful code for image processing (including resizing), I've used these a number of times.

Assuming your images are large, you may want to look at JAI and use either embedded thumbnails or sub-sampling to reduce the memory needed.

```
public static BufferedImage getThumb(ImageReader reader, int size) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img;

    try {
        if (reader.getNumThumbnails(0) > 0) {
            img = reader.readThumbnail(0, 0);
        } else {
            ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
            param.setSourceSubsampling(4, 4, 0, 0);
            img = reader.read(0); //read(0, param);
        }
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        img = null;
    }

    return img != null ? resizeImage(img, size) : null;
}   

public static BufferedImage getThumb(File file, double scale) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try {
        Class<?> c = ImageUtil.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("javax.media.jai.JAI");
        Class<?> ic = ImageUtil.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("javax.media.jai.Interpolation");
        Class<?> sc = ImageUtil.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("javax.media.jai.operator.ScaleDescriptor");
        Method jaiCreate = c.getMethod("create", String.class, Object.class);
        Method getInstance = findMethod(ic, "getInstance");
        Method sdCreate = findMethod(sc, "create");

        if (c != null) { 
            Object image = jaiCreate.invoke(null, "fileload", file.getAbsolutePath());              
            Object[] params = { image, (float) scale, (float) scale,
                    0.0f, 0.0f, getInstance.invoke(null, 2), null };
            Object sd = sdCreate.invoke(null, params);
            Method m = sd.getClass().getMethod("getAsBufferedImage");
            img = (BufferedImage) m.invoke(sd);
        }
    } catch (Throwable tt) {
        System.out.println("Could not read image using JAI, maybe JAI is not installed.");
        System.out.println(tt);
    }

    return img;
}
```

Comment: i am setting IMG_WIDTH statically as 600 from outside the function.

Comment: What size (dimension wise) are you input image, are they always of a fixed aspect ratio?, if not you are going to end up with some stretched images.

Comment: I got what you meant. but the major issue is the heap space error.

Comment: What size (dimension wise) are your input images?  If your source and target images are large then you are going to run out of memory and affects the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How do you launch this process? This code does seem to be cleaning up the images properly.

Only option is to increase heap size by adding -Xmx 512m  (to increase heap size to 512 MB for example) as one of VM command line options.

Comment: I did the same. But it is not the proper solution.

Comment: What is the size (and resolution) of images? If images are large then you do have to ensure sufficient heap to load 3 - 4 images at the same time

Comment: Input images are getting from a filechooser.I am getting heap space error only if we choose more than 15 images.         
I am running a for loop from 0 to no. of selected images. Inside that loop, I am calling the above mentioned function for creating thumbnail.

Comment: What is average size / resolution of these images? Or does that happen regardless of resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Creating thumbnails in Java requires the appropriate tool for this: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Call it from Java, and enjoy the results. It will always be better, more fail safe and faster than everything you can do in Java with Libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

Check [**thumbnailator**](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/)